# Drupal generating broken URLs containing "http" twice

Tags: theming, uri

My drupal site website started recently generating broken links/URLs within markup. It might have happened after I updated to version 7.41 or due to recent module update. I'm not sure.

Example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mydomain.nethttp:/" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mydomain.nethttp:/sites/default/files/css/css_xE-rWrJf-fncB6ztZfd2huxqgxu4WO-qwma6Xer30m4.css" media="all" />
```

Any idea what is going on? My drupal is hosted at the top of domain and not in a subdirectory. I was fine for years and didn't have to set $base_url in settings.php or anything.

My site uses clean urls and I double checked that rewrite apache module is on and working correctly.

I did try setting the $base_url in settings.php, this made the front page load correctly, however when I visit any node the apache returns 404, e.g. in access.log I see:
"GET /content/some-nice-article-i-had HTTP/1.1" 404

I'm using Apache/2.4.17 and PHP 5.6.14 on Archinux.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Apache 2.4.17 break rewrite functionality when fastcgi PHP is used. With mod_php everything is working fome but I'm looking forward to Apache 2.4.18 or 2.5.